Autohotkey how to map shift + character
Here is my script
5::(   ; work: when press 5 turn into "("
%::5   ; not work: when press % (shift 5) I want it turn into "5" but it turn into "%"

How to fix the line 2?
BTW, I want to make a layout that inspired by Programmer Dvorak Keyboard Layout

I found the answers: use the "shift" character: "+"
+%::5

